# Read two files in real time

Tags: bash

If I have two devices connected via USB (in linux) and would like to read them both at the same time. Essentially, they never terminate, but I want to read them whenever they read a line (each line ends with `\r\n`).

Here is what it would look like in Python:

```
from threading import Thread

usb0 = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", "r")
usb1 = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", "r")

def read0():
    while True: print usb0.readline().strip()

def read1():
    while True: print usb1.readline().strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = read0).start()
    Thread(target = read1).start()
```

Is there any way to do that in bash. I know you can do this:

```
while read -r -u 4 line1 && read -r -u 5 line2; do
  echo $line1
  echo $line2
done 4</dev/ttyUSB0 5</dev/ttyUSB1
```

That, however, actually cuts off part of my line every couple times a second. I am really more curious if this is possible and don't really need it since it is pretty easy with threading in a modern programming language like Java or Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to start a thread in bash but you can fork off two background jobs for the reading. You need to spread the read actions into two separate `while` constructs and put them into background using the ampersand operator `&`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure that the background jobs will 
# get stopped if Ctrl+C is pressed
trap "kill %1 %2; exit 1" SIGINT SIGTERM

# Start a read loop for both inputs in background
while IFS= read -r line1 ; do
  echo "$line1"
  # do something with that line ...
done </dev/ttyUSB0 &

while IFS= read -r line2 ; do
  echo "$line2"
  # do something with that line ...
done </dev/ttyUSB1 &

# Wait for background processes to finish
wait %1 %2
echo "jobs finished"
```

Comment: Thanks for killing the unkillable. I was just about to look that up. That works better than I thought it could work. I wasn't sure how to start *two* background jobs because I always get an error when I do `cat file1 &; cat file2 &`, so thanks!

Comment: Well; not to ruin your fun, but you can just do `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 & cat /dev/ttyUSB1 &` :P

Comment: I like your solution, though - even if it is more complicated - because you can prepend or append stuff to the begginning or end of the line (I like to add "1:" if it is coming from usb 0 and "2:" if it is coming from usb1

Comment: ^ ^  Also, I just said I would like to read two never ending files at the same time. :) I still like yours better.

Comment: (thx :) )  Yes, or adding timestamps etc. Depends on the use case if `cat` or `while read ...` should be used. Also note that the output will not being the same when cat or line-wise reading is used as cat will read - and output - multiple lines at once if used in a pipe (meaning stdin isn't a terminal) ...